# Miniconda VS Code Output Not Running From Code Runner Output Tab

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda, vscode-code-runner

I am an absolute beginner using Python and have been trying to use Miniconda environments.  I created a couple of environments and tried to use them with VS Code.  Here is my workflow:

1. Open command prompt > activate my desired environment.
2. Open VS Code > Select my desired environment on the Command Palette.
3. Run Code.

This is what my VS Code terminal shows:
[image]

My issue is that I have been getting mixed results.  Sometimes my code runs on the terminal, but I expected the output to show on Code Runner's Output tab.  Sometimes the Output tab shows an error importing packages that are explicitly downloaded on my environment.  Am I using the correct workflow with these two tools?

Comment: Probably your answer will be "Of course, I know it!", but have you tried to set the right conda interpreter? Press Ctrl+Shift+P to open the code Command Palette and then type "Python: Select Interpreter", to select it from the list.

Comment: @Myron_Ben4 I am an absolute beginner, so please don't worry.  I won't be offended when by any of your suggestions.  I double checked your suggestions and can confirm that that step did not work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using both *[Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)* and *[Python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)* extensions. It is not recommended to use the *Code Runner* extension without special requirements. **Please use the official extension ***Python*** to execute the code.**

[image]

##### Explanation:

- *Code Runner* will display the result in the **OUTPUT** panel by default, and the **Python** extension will display the result in the integrated terminal
- The interpreter you choose for the current workspace (shown in the lower right corner) only applies to the **Python** extension, because that's what it does. `Select Interpreter` function has no effect on *Code Runner*.
- If you use *Code Runner*, it uses the `python -u path\to\name.py` command to execute the script, then `python` will be the python interpreter configured by the environment variable path in your machine, not necessarily the one you choose in vscode.

##### Other information:

If you need *Code Runner* to output in the terminal, you can add the following settings.

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
```

The name of the terminal tab is `code`, which is the green box in the picture. The red box is the terminal executed by the **Python** extension.

[image]

##### Useful links:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial
- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics
- https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/README.md#configuration

Comment: Hi @JialeDu, Thank you so much for your help!  I followed YouTube tutorials and I saw they suggested that extension.  If there are no benefits to run my code on the output tab instead of the terminal, then I will delete that extension.  Thank you so much!